# Help in selecting options for low quality posts

Tags: discussion

While reviewing low quality posts such as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/74698) one, what option should I select after notifying the user that more details are needed in the answer? In this case, the user is already notified and I upvoted the comment.

The options that are available to me are,

- **Looks Ok** - This option couldn't be selected as the answer still needs more details.
- **Edit** - This option is also not applicable.
- **Recommend Deletion** - I think I should go for this but the problem is if 2  users having more than 10k rep select this, the person who answered the question will not get a chance to add contents to the answer.

What should be the course of action to help facilitate the new user fix his answer in such scenarios? Shouldn't we give the new user some time to fix the answer or I should simply select **recommend deletion**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give the OP the chance to fix their post, leave them a comment and then choose **Skip**. Since you haven't actually fixed the issue with the post, that seems the most reasonable option since it will let you move on to the next review item and won't clear it from the queue.