# No vote options on low quality posts queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've seen some discussions regarding voting to delete wrong/low quality answers and it seems that is the incorrect course of action but instead they should be down-voted.

Based on that I wonder why there is no option to vote when reviewing posts in the *low quality posts* queue?  I think it would be beneficial to have this option for both answers and questions in the low quality queue.

Related posts I have found:

- [When to vote to delete an answer?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4772/237982)
- [Low quality posts from high rep users](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/237982)
- [Flagging questions that are “Very Low Quality”?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4192/237982)
- [Help in selecting options for low quality posts](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3333/237982)

I think in many of these cases, the ability to up or down vote would provide another useful option for these questions/answers.

---

It seems like the biggest argument against this is that a post will be "hammered with downvotes."  However, in my opinion, this is exactly the point.  If a post truly is low quality but not a valid reason to flag it, it *should* be downvoted. In contrast, a post that is flagged as low quality but is actually a valid answer would receive more upvotes, as it should.

Comment: It can also happen that a post turns up on LQ but deserves to be upvoted ;-).

Comment: Found some MSE history: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228738/add-downvote-option-to-low-quality-review-queue-list-of-potential-actions

Comment: @JeffSchaller:  That is an interesting take on it but I still think it would benefit the LQ queue in the same way it does the First Posts and Late Answers queues.

Comment: @StephenKitt Like this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/243170  :)

Comment: @Anthony LOL indeed!